# Wi-Fi client and Group Owner at the same time

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct

I'm building a network over wifip2p. If a device is a legacy client of a Group Owner can it act as a Group Owner for other devices?

Answer (score 0):

No, it can not. But it will continue as a legacy WiFi Access-Point.

If one of the connected clients is a non-WiFi-Direct device (STA) ,the P2P-GO will act like a traditional WiFi Access point. Which means other devices will be able to connect to it, but it will not support the additional power saving mechanisms in WiFi-Direct [Opportunistic power save and notice-Of-absence]. These power saving mechanisms makes P2P-GO different from normal WiFi Access-point as , it helps P2P-GO it reduce power consumption

Answer (score 0):

Sure, It can act as Legacy client in Group A and be the Group Owner of its own Group B. The main scenario for this topology is when Group A GO does not cover all the peers present in the scenario, so this legacy client is used in order to reach those missing peers, of course if It can reach them.